# Querying sequence in H2 with MODE as DB2

Tags: h2

I am using H2 1.4.191 to unit test some of code that runs against DB2 in production. I have created a sequence in both H2 and DB2 like this-

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TABLENAME_SEQ 
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
NO CYCLE
CACHE 50;
```

And the code  queries it like this-

```
SELECT NEXTVAL FOR TABLENAME_SEQ FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Since the code is basically meant to run against DB2, it selects against `SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`.

The H2 URL for unit test specifies mode as DB2, does it mean that H2 would query against SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 or am I missing something here.

```
jdbc:h2:./testdb;MV_STORE=FALSE;MVCC=FALSE;MODE=DB2
```

Here is the error that I get-
 org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT NEXTVAL FOR TABLENAME_SEQ FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1"; SQL statement:
SELECT NEXTVAL FOR TABLENAME_SEQ FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 [42000-191]

I know that H2's systax for selecting from q sequence is different, but since I specified mode=db2, should it work with DB2 systax?

Answer (score 0):

When you set your connection just add INIT instruction in the url :

```
jdbc:h2:./testdb;MV_STORE=FALSE;MVCC=FALSE;MODE=DB2;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS SYSIBM\\;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1()
```

Please note the double backslash (\) is only required within Java. The backslash(es) before ; within the INIT is required.

I hope this will help you